# In HMVC, how to load a model from another module?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

on the server I can not load a model that is in another module in the HMVC, framework of the Codeigniter framework, I tried this way:

```
Class Contract extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Contract_model', 'contract');
        $this->load->model('register/customer_model', 'customer');
        $this->load->model('register/daydue_model', 'due');
    }
}
```

Structure

[image]

In the localhost works quietly, since the server is giving this error::

```
Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Daydue_model
```

Comment: shoud be like this `$this->load->model('register/DayDue_model', 'due');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you uploading on server use casesensitive it does not create problem on localhost. your model name is incorrect.

Do it like this

```
$this->load->model('register/daydue_model', 'due');
```

And rename your model name to Daydue_model and check the class name same is the name of model like:

```
class Daydue_model extends CI_Model
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the same way that you mentioned and it did not work.

Comment: The rules of codeginater are that model name first latter should be start form caps and the remains will be in lower case and use underscore instead of space. apply the rules on you model name eg Daydue_model and your class name must be same

Comment: if my answer help you please don't hesitate to check it as green